# Making a movie into a .gif file

Tags: conversion, gif

How do I convert a movie into an animated gif in OS X? I just want to convert a movie file (any file format) into an animated gif (so, obviously no sound).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a webservice called Gifninja ;) http://gifninja.com/animated-gifs/create